# Display objects in grid with collapsible elements

Tags: java, swing, object

I have some Objects with multiple elements that I'd like to display in a grid. Every object should be a row and the columns should be:

Object.name/category | Button | Object.targetLocation | Object.notes

In the Object.name column I also need a tab, i.e. it should look like this:

```
Category1
  Name1
  Name2
  Name3
Category2
  Name4
  ...
```

Where each Category and the corresponding rows can be collapsed/expanded.

I have zero idea with what kind of swing element(s) I should work here. Perhaps a GridBagLayout would work, but I'm not sure about the collapsing/expanding of categories with that. Is there any simple way to do this without excessive coding?

[This is it!](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-treegrid.html)

Comment: Maybe you can post an image of how you want your GUI to look?

Comment: A bit hard to do since I don't have a similar one available.

Comment: Use drawing software, like Windows _Paint_ or maybe the suggestions in this _Stack ___Exchange___ question: [Open source tool to draw GUI mockups](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/open-source-tool-to-draw-gui-mockups)

Comment: I believe you want a _treetable_. Google for the terms ___java swing treetable___. I found this [example](http://esus.com/example-of-treetable/). Also, JavaFX has a [TreeTableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) Maybe you should use JavaFX instead of _Swing_ ?

Comment: Thank you, I should be able to work with that.